# How do I create a Query that calculates the adverage of a computed column

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, window-functions, calculated-columns

I need to create a query that shows the average productivity for editors that have worked on more than one book except for their first book published with a precision of 0.01 pages/day.

I'm having trouble finding a way to get the number of days since the last `DateOfPublication` column and use it to divide it from the `NoOfPages` column.

The columns to be displayed are

`EditorName`

`BookName`

computed column `AverageProductivity`

Here are the tables and their columns

```
AGENT  AgentID (PK,varchar(11), not null)
       AgentName (varchar(25), not null)

BOOK   BookName (PK, varchar(45), not null)
       Genre (varchar(25), not null)
       DateOfPublication (date, not null)
       NoOfPages (int, not null)
       WriterID (PK, FK,, varchar(11), not null)
       EditorID (FK, varchar(11), not null)

EDITOR EditorID (PK, varchar(11), not null)
       EditorName (varchar(25), not null)
       Mentors_EditorID (FK, varchar(11), null)

WRITER WriterID (PK, varchar(11), not null)
       WriterName (varchar(25), not null)
       AgentID (FK, varchar(11), not null)
```

Sample Data

```
insert into BOOK (BookName, WriterID, Genre, DateOfPublication, NoOfPages, EditorID)
values ('Valley of Heroes','10','Fiction','2010-01-12',874,'20');
insert into BOOK (BookName, WriterID, Genre, DateOfPublication, NoOfPages, EditorID)
values ('The Ruler''s Return','11','Fantasy','2012-03-14',765,'22');
insert into BOOK (BookName, WriterID, Genre, DateOfPublication, NoOfPages, EditorID)
values ('eRobot','11','Fantasy','2011-04-15',264,'20');
insert into BOOK (BookName, WriterID, Genre, DateOfPublication, NoOfPages, EditorID)
values ('An Uncle''s Letters','12','Fiction','2012-06-12',258,'20');
insert into BOOK (BookName, WriterID, Genre, DateOfPublication, NoOfPages, EditorID)
values ('Pretty flowers','13','Album','2013-01-31',148,'22');
insert into BOOK (BookName, WriterID, Genre, DateOfPublication, NoOfPages, EditorID)
values ('A Tale of Lions','12','Fantasy','2012-08-17',301,'21');
insert into BOOK (BookName, WriterID, Genre, DateOfPublication, NoOfPages, EditorID)
values ('eRobot','13','Sci Fi','2012-10-04',465,'23');
```

The Query is producing the correct Columns now, credit to GMB, but The calculated column is showing 0 values.

Here is the Query...

```
select * from (
    select 
    e.EditorName,
    b.BookName,
    round(
        NoOfPages/datediff(
            day, 
            lag(b.DateOfPublication) over(partition by b.EditorID order by b.DateOfPublication),
            DateOfPublication
        ),
        2
    ) AverageProductivity       
from book b
inner join editor e on e.EditorID = b.EditorID 
) x where AverageProductivity is not null
```

Results...

```
Melanie eRobot  0
Melanie An Uncle's Letters  0
George  Pretty flowers  0
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Ill add some sample data and the results

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window function `lag()` to recover the date of the previous publication of the same editor.

Then, `datediff(day, ...)` can give you the difference between the publication date of the last book and the current one, in days.

Finally, divide the number of pages of the current book with the day difference, use `round()` to limit the number of decimals, and you are done.

For the first book of an editor, `lag()` returns `null`, which will propagate in the computation, resulting in the computed column showing `null` as well.

```
select 
    e.EditorName,
    b.BookName,
    round(
        NoOfPages/datediff(
            day, 
            lag(b.DateOfPublication) over(partition by b.EditorID order by b.DateOfPublication),
            DateOfPublication
        ),
        2
    ) AverageProductivity       
from book b
inner join editor e on e.EditorID = b.EditorID
```

If you want to skip the records that correspond to the first book of each editor, then you can wrap the query:

```
select * from (
    -- above query
) x where AverageProductivity is not null
```

Comment: Alright, I ran that and now I see the correct Editors but the AverageProductivity column is showing 0s for their productivity

Comment: @YHapticY: the only reason that I see is that the division returns something smaller than 0.01 (or the number of pages is 0). You can remove the surrounding round() and see what comes up. Also, you can have a look at what datediff() and NoOfPages return by putting them in separated columns in the result set.

Comment: When I try to remove the round() i get "No column name was specified for column 3 of x"